# Difference between C++ MEX and C MEX

Tags: c++, c, matlab, sockets, mex

I wrote a TCPIP-Socket-Connection with Server and Client in C++, which works quite nice in VisualStudio. Now I want to use the C++ - Client in MATLAB/Simulink through MEX-Files and later in a S-Function.
I found two descriptions about MEX-Files.

1. [C++ MEX File Application](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cpp-mex-file-applications.html) Just for C++
2. [C/C++ MEX Files](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/write-cc-mex-files.html) C/C++

Now I am confused, which one would be the one to take. I wrote some easy programms with the second, but always got into problems with datatypes. I think, it is because the given examples and functions are only for C and not for C++.

I appreciate any help! Thank you very much!

Comment: depends if you want C or C++, no other mistery. Note that its essentially the same for MATLAB. You can either just do C++ or have C/C++ or more C-like code.

Comment: I have never used C. I want to use C++. Is it possible to use both of the two for writing c++?

Comment: Yes, C++ supports mostly all C code on it.

Comment: Note that the C interface doesn't require a C compiler. This is about the way that functions are called. In C++ you can use `extern C` in function declarations to tell the compiler to call a function as if it were a C function. You can use the C interface from many other programming languages too.

Comment: *"... you can use extern C in function declarations to tell the compiler to call a function as if it were a C function ..."* Note that this is already done in the mex.h etc. header files for you. You don't have to manually add this to your mex source code.

Answer (score 9):

**The differences:**

1. The C interface described [in the second link](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/write-cc-mex-files.html) is much, much older (I used this interface way back in 1998). You can create a MEX-file with this interface and have it run on a large set of different versions of MATLAB. You can use it from C as well as C++ code.
2. The C++-only interface described [in the first link](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cpp-mex-file-applications.html) is new in MATLAB R2018a (the C++ classes to manipulate MATLAB arrays were introduced in R2017b, but the ability to write a MEX-file was new in R2018a). MEX-files you write with this interface will not run on prior versions of MATLAB.

   Additionally, this interface (finally!) allows for creating shared-data copies, in-place operations, etc. (the stuff we have been asking for for many years, but they didn't want to put into the old C interface because they worried it would be too complex for the average MEX-file writer).

**Another change to be aware of:**

In R2018a, MATLAB also changed the way that complex arrays are stored in memory. In older versions of MATLAB, the real and imaginary components are stored in separate memory blocks. In R2018a and on, they are stored in the same memory block, in the same fashion as you would likely use in your own code.

[This affects MEX-files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/do-i-need-to-upgrade-my-mex-files-to-use-interleaved-complex.html)! If you MEX-file uses complex data, it needs to read and write them in the way that MATLAB stores them. If you run a MEX-file compiled for an older version of MATLAB, or compile a MEX-file using the current default building options in R2018a, a complex array will be copied to the old storage model before being passed to the MEX-file. A new compile option to the `mex` command, `-R2018a`, creates MEX-files that pass the data in the new storage model unchanged. But those MEX-files will not be compatible with previous versions of MATLAB.

**How to choose?**

- If you need your MEX-files to run on versions of MATLAB prior to the newest R2018a, use the old C interface, you don't have a choice.
- If you want to program in C, use the old C interface.
- If you need to use complex data, and *don't want to incur the cost of the copy*, you need to target R2018a and newer, and R2017b and older, separately. You need to write separate code for these two "platforms". The older versions can only be targeted with the C interface. For the newer versions you can use either interface.
- If you appreciate the advantages of modern C++ and would like to take advantage of them, and are targeting only the latest and greatest MATLAB version, then use the new C++ interface. I haven't tried it out yet, but from the documentation it looks to be very well designed.

Comment: With the old C interface, you could make shared data copies only using undocumented functionality. This functionality has been removed in R2018a, so code that used it no longer works. See [this question on MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/396103-mxcreateshareddatacopy-no-longer-supported-in-r2018a)  for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to use an older version, so I will choose the second link.

Comment: To be clear, the undocumented mxCreateSharedDataCopy( ) function that has been used in C/C++ mex routines is still present in the libraries.  It is just that the mex command intentionally disables the user linking with them in the -R2018a model. There are ways around this, but again you have to resort to a hack which may break in the future. The new C++ interface (which I haven't used yet) hides all of the shared data stuff intentionally, so it operates like normal MATLAB variables at the m-file level. Fine for what it is, but it does remove the user from direct control over their data copies.

Comment: And, I would add, that there *still* appear to be no inspection methods for determining the shared status of a variable (isaSharedDataCopy, isaReferenceCopy, etc.). So it is *still* impossible from a programmer's prospective to know for certain when an action will or will not result in a deep data copy. This is still one of the biggest shortcomings of the API, both the old one and the new one.  You still have to resort to hacks to find out the sharing status, and even the hacks are not 100% reliable.